# How to use Laravel and GitHub for multiple programmers?

Tags: php, github, laravel-5

I have a question about laravel and GitHub. Why does laravel automatically ignore vendor directory.

It just makes it so hard if I want to use work on the project with two computers, and after another computer download the GitHub version of laravel project (which is missing some files), the server does not work.

The command line is telling me the following:

> Warning: require(C:\app\XAMPP\htdocs\xxxx\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\app\XAMPP\htdocs\xxxx\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\app\XAMPP\htdocs\xxxx\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\app\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in C:\app\XAMPP\htdocs\xxxx\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. If you have a laravel project which you cloned from GitHub it is very likely that the vendor folder is part of the `.gitignore` file. This is standard to all projects since it's assumed that you won't be the only person working on this and even if you are, paths change from one workstation to the other. In my home I might host things under `~/bitoiu` and at work under `c:\ubs\dev`. Adding the vendor folder is the first thing I do when I create a new git project.

Comment: You use `composer install` to "fill" the vendor directory. That's also the reason Laravel ignores it, vendor is supposed to be maintainable and changeable, and your application files are not stored there.

Comment: `composer update` with composer.json file will update your vendor folder.

Comment: So you clone your project, type `composer install` or `composer update` and that's it, you have your shared stuff. Then you can also send updates via `git push`, add additional dependencies etc. without causing any conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

Under most circumstances, the `vendor` directory shouldn't be kept in source control. This has nothing to with Laravel; it's the way you generally work with Composer.

The way to ensure that everyone in your group (and your production servers) are running the same dependencies is to keep `composer.lock` and `composer.json` in source control, that way members of your team can check out the repo and run `composer install` NOT `composer update`.

Then, when you're ready to update a package, you can run `composer update` and commit the changes to `composer.lock` and `composer.json`.

Comment: I totally agree with `edcs` on this -- you keep `vendor` out of source control so that your repository isn't burdened by libraries that are available in other means of source control anyway, and would make it overly-large and redundant.